# Know when an object is created

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-runtime

Is there any way to use the ObjC runtime library, or Cocoa, to be notified when an object is created, for example, after it returns from the `init` method?

I want to achieve this without modifying the object, or subclassing it (no subclass on `NSObject`, for example) and without method swizzling (I already know how to do that).

Comment: Not without code in the class or _some_ kind of interposing (such as of `class_createInstance()`, and including swizzling), no. This isn't something you would normally care about, and if it is you should be able to change the code. Can you elaborate on your end goal?

Comment: You could wrap the object in a proxy instance and forward selectors through to the target.

Comment: @JoshCaswell , I'm working on a class that simulates the private _UIAppearance behavior. This to add UIAppearance support to objects that usually doesn't support it (look at this post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732885/uiappearance-proxy-for-custom-objects) ). I've just created a proxy class and it works good, but I would like to inject the invocations "automatically" after the target object is initialized, without calling the "startForwarding" method from the initialized object itself. But this is only for convenience, so I was looking for a "non invasive" method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no sanctioned way to be notified when a method executes, unless it specifically notes that it returns a notification, or a pointer to some kind of callback, a block, etc.  While swizzling may be one way of going about it, proxying is probably your best bet.  Instead of messing with the selector for an entire class, you interpose yourself "as" the class by implementing all its properties and/or forwarding selectors to the target object.  In this way, NSProxy and subclasses can be used as wrappers around normal objects, meaning you can respond to any kind of method that happens to be sent through your proxy before forwarding it on to the target.  A simple proxy can be modeled after the sample below:

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *const CFIProxyDidInitializeTargetNotification;

@interface CFIObjectProxy : NSProxy {
    __strong Foo *_target;
}

- (id)init;

@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSArray* bars;

@end

//...

#import "CFIObjectProxy.h"

NSString *const CFIProxyDidInitializeTargetNotification = @"CFIProxyDidInitializeTargetNotification";

@implementation CFIObjectProxy

- (id)init {

    _target = [[Foo alloc]init];
    [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter postNotificationName:CFIProxyDidInitializeTargetNotification object:nil];

    return self;
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation {
    [invocation invokeWithTarget:_target];
}

- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)sel {
    return [_target methodSignatureForSelector:sel];
}

- (NSString *)description {
    return [_target description];
}

- (NSString *)debugDescription {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@:%p> Proxy for Object: %@", NSStringFromClass(self.class), self, _target];
}

- (NSArray*)bars {
    return [_target bars];
}

@end
```

Comment: Where does `- (NSArray *)bars` come from?

Comment: Need I really include the header of Foo?

Comment: It's a covered method? That just seems unnecessary since you're forwarding everything anyways.

Comment: Just nice to show that you don't have to rely on forwarding.  That, and it allows you to use the proxy as though it were the underlying object.  Xcode is none too happy about proxies without explicit properties, etc.

Comment: Thanks, the proxy solution is not good for me (I can't add a proxy around objects, they must be used transparently), but at this point I understand that there are no other possibilities to achieve it without subclassing or swizzling...so this is the correct (and more complete) answer :-)

Comment: as I said earlier, this isn't transparent and only an option for active allocations

Comment: Despite its lack of transparency (which, one could argue, is besides the point), this solution is far safer than overriding the memory-related methods in a class.  Swizzling +alloc is basically playing a game of Russian roulette with the runtime, and yet I get downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

Per default, the runtime doesn't record this. I think I'd use swizzling BUT as you don't want this...  I think that CodaFi's idea of wrapping the object in a proxy is best ALTHOUGH this is only an option for allocations you manually do AFAICS

so if you want it to be truly transparent, swizzle after all I'd say